# web.config with StaticFileModule has no effect when running asp.net core app via docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, iis

in my contentroot I have a folder `.well-known` which has a web.config with this content:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
        </handlers>
     </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

This makes the files from inside the folder accessible, when I run the app in `IIS`, so I can run in the browser
`myapp/.wellknown/aaa.txt`

However when I run this same application via docker I can't access the `aaa.txt`, seems like the `web.config` has no effect

(when running via docker the `.well-known` folder is attached as a volume)

EDIT/current solution: for now I changed my volume mapping to `/app/wwwroot` instead

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it solved please share your answer, if not, did you get any error message?

Comment: @samwu I changed my volume mapping to /app/wwwroot instead